# Compute $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \left(\sin x + \cos x\right)^{1/x}$

Tags: limits

I hit a snag while solving exponential functions whose limits are given.

Question:

$$\lim_{x\to0} \left(\sin x + \cos x\right)^\left(1/x\right)$$

My Approach:

I am using the followin relation to solve the question of these type.

$$\lim_{x\to0} \left(1 + x\right)^\left(1/x\right) = e \qquad(2)$$

But now how should i convert my above question so that i can apply the rule as mentioned in $(2)$.

Conclusion:

First of all help will be appreciated.

Second how to solve functions of such kind in a quick method.

Thanks,

P.S.(Feel free to edit my question if you find any errors or mistakes in my question)

Comment: @Crostul The LH step in this case would be absurd, as in every situation where one is after a limit $\lim\limits_{x\to0}g(x)/x$ with $g$ differentiable at $0$ and $g(0)=0$.

Comment: @Did , please elaborate why would the LH step be absurd?

Comment: Because using LH to find $\lim\limits_{x\to0} g(x)/h(x)$ when $g(0)=h(0)=0$ requires to compute $g'(0)$ and $h'(0)$. But, in the case when $h(x)=x$, one already knows that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}g(x)/x=g'(0)$ **by definition of the derivative of $g$** since $g(x)/x=(g(x)-g(0))/(x-0)$. So, invoking LH here amounts to a beautifully (?) absurd logical circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case the best idea is take logarithm, and then use De l'Hopital. $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln (\sin x + \cos x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x - \sin x}{\sin x + \cos x} = 1$$ Hence the answer is $e^{1}=e$.

Comment: See comment on main.

Comment: It isn't $e^{-1}$ anyway

Comment: @Crostul , When apply the $\lim_{x\to0}$ shouldn't the answer be $1$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, take $\cos x$ out:
$$\lim_{x\to0} \left(\sin x + \cos x\right)^\left(1/x\right)=\\
\lim_{x\to0} \left(\cos x\right)^\left(1/x\right)\cdot \lim_{x\to0} \left(1+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)^\left(1/x\right)=\\
\color{blue}{\lim_{x\to0} \left(1-2\sin^2 \frac x2\right)^\left(1/x\right)}\cdot \color{red}{\lim_{x\to0} \left(1+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)^\left(1/x\right)}=\color{blue}1\cdot \color{red}e=e,$$
because using the relation you want:
$$\color{blue}{\lim_{x\to0} \left(1-2\sin^2 \frac x2\right)^\left(1/x\right)=\\
\lim_{x\to0} \left[\left(1+\left(-2\sin^2 \frac x2\right)\right)^\frac{1}{-2\sin^2 \frac x2}\right]^{\frac{-2\sin^2 \frac x2}{x}}=e^0=1};\\
\color{red}{\lim_{x\to0} \left(1+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)^\left(1/x\right)=\\
\lim_{x\to0} \left[\left(1+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)^{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}\right]^\frac{\sin x}{x\cos x}=e^1=e}.$$

Comment: thanks you helped me find one more way to approach questions of this kind

Answer (score 0):

Another standard way works with enforcing a $\color{red}{1}$  in the basis and considering the resulting exponent:

\begin{eqnarray*} \left(\sin x + \cos x\right)^{1/x}
  & =  &   \left( \color{red}{1} + (\color{blue}{\sin x + \cos x - 1})\right)^{1/x}\\
  & =  &    \left (\left( 1 + (\color{blue}{\sin x + \cos x - 1})\right)^{1/(\color{blue}{\sin x + \cos x - 1})}\right)^{\frac{\color{blue}{\sin x + \cos x - 1}}{x}}  \\
  & \stackrel {x \to 0}{\longrightarrow} &   e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x + \cos x - 1}{x}}\\
  & = &  e^{1+\cos'(0)} = e \\
\end{eqnarray*}